# How to apply classes to Vue.js Functional Component from parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Suppose I have a functional component:

```
<template functional>
    <div>Some functional component</div>
</template>
```

Now I render this component in some parent with classes:

```
<parent>
    <some-child class="new-class"></some-child>
</parent>
```

Resultant `DOM` doesn't have `new-class` applied to the Functional child component. Now as I understand, `Vue-loader` compiles **Functional** component against `render` function `context` as [explained here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/functional.html). That means classes won't be directly applied and merge intelligently.

Question is - **how can I make Functional component play nicely with the externally applied class when using a template?**

*Note: I know it is easily possible to do so via render function:*

```
Vue.component("functional-comp", {
    functional: true,
    render(h, context) {
        return h("div", context.data, "Some functional component");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### TL;DR;

Use `data.staticClass` to get the class, and bind the other attributes using `data.attrs`

```html
<template functional>
  <div class="my-class" :class="data.staticClass || ''" v-bind="data.attrs">
    //...
  </div>
</template>
```

### Explanation:

`v-bind` binds all the other stuff, and you may not need it, but it will bind attributes like `id` or `style`. The problem is that you can't use it for `class` because that's a reserved js object so vue uses `staticClass`, so binding has to be done manually using `:class="data.staticClass"`.

This will fail if the `staticClass` property is not defined, by the parent, so you should use `:class="data.staticClass || ''"`

### Example:

I can't show this as a fiddle, since only *"Functional components defined as a Single-File Component in a *.vue file also receives proper template compilation"*

I've got a working codesandbox though: https://codesandbox.io/s/z64lm33vol

Comment: To apply both static and dynamic classes from a parent, e.g. `<some-child class="a" :class="{b: true}"/>` use `:class="[data.staticClass, data.class]"` in the child.

Comment: How to bind all regular static attributes on childComponent:
(1) use `:class="data.staticClass"` for classes
(2) use `:style="data.staticStyle"` for styles
(3) use `v-bind="data.attrs"`  for id etc.

Answer (score 1):

Render function inside a functional component example, to supplement @Daniel's answer:

```
render(createElement, { data } {
  return createElement(
    'div',
    {
      class: {
        ...(data.staticClass && {
          [data.staticClass]: true,
        })
      },
      attrs: {
        ...data.attrs,
      }
    }
  )
}
```

We can use ES6 computed property name in order to set a static class.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use props to pass attributes to components
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props