# In Vue.js template-based functional components, how to pass down the full context?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm learning about [Vue.js' functional components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) and, the `createElement` way being a bit hard to read, I want to use the template-based way (`<template functional>`).

But there is one thing I'm not sure how to do : the equivalent of `createElement('button', context.data)` which passes down **all** props, attributes, listeners, etc.

The documentation mentions `v-bind="data.attrs" v-on="listeners"` but that does not pass down everything: my `class="mr-0"` gets lost for exemple.

I can "fix" it by adding a `:class="data.staticClass"` but that's getting ugly and cumbersome, plus I'm not sure if it works with dynamic classes.

Does someone know a better way?

---

Edit: did some debugging, and here is the `data` object Vue gives me in this particular case: `{"staticClass":"mr-0","on":{}}`

Comment: How does `data.attrs` look like? BTW, `class` is just another normal attribute, if you want to use `v-bind="data.attrs"` to bind classes, `data.attrs` has to contain `class: your-classes`.

Comment: Added in edit: `{"staticClass":"mr-0","on":{}}` that's all I have in `data`

Comment: hmm. Haven't used functional components before, But according to [this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth). It doesn't seem the `data` property should have a `staticClass` key.

Comment: see my answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50728775/197546