# When to use functional components in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have just read about functional components in Vue.js 2. ([Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components))

The major benefits of function components seems to be performance improvement:

> Since functional components are just functions, they’re much cheaper
> to render.

It seems like that for emitting `events` from functional components an event listener has to be added manually. However `props` are fully accessable.

What is a good rule of thumb when to use a functional component instead of a class component? Should I prefer using the functional components when I implement a stateless component in general? Or are there any other limitations to functional component in Vue.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just thinking about this the other day. ..

There are some additional caveats to functional components (e.g. passing classes requires custom handling [How to apply classes to Vue.js Functional Component from parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355045/how-to-apply-classes-to-vue-js-functional-component-from-parent-component))

The rule of thumb I'd use is when the component is when you are using many instances of the component, (so you get a tangible performance benefit) and preferably it's not too complicated in terms of interaction (since you lose most Vue magic)